# Rotating Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem when rotating my Android App after doing some basic interactions, I keep getting a null error;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

Whilst I know what the error means, I cannot see any reason why it would happen when rotating the device (happens both on my physical dev device and in the emulator). The code its complaining about is (which is in my onAttach method in a fragment);

```
TextView totalMatchGoals = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtResInfoGoals);
```

Does rotating the device cause the view to refresh? Even then I can't think why that would cause problems.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do your checking inside `onCreateView()` after inflating the layout, or `onViewCreated()`, when views actually exist.

Comment: Thanks. When calling that findViewById if I don't rotate the view, it works fine, where I'm struggling is why it works in the onAttach but when I rotate it that it doesnt.

Comment: Don't struggle, study a little bit more, and think: you are trying to get a view. When you rotate the device, the view and activities are destroyed, so a new instance of both activity and fragment are created. Never try to get views inside `onAttach()` as that method is only used to bind the fragment to the hosting activity if the latter implements a fragment interface. Do it instead on one of the methods I mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

If you have not configured your AndroidManifest.xml to do otherwise, Android will destroy and recreate your whole activity when an orientation change is detected.

When recreating the activity, onAttach is called before the view is populated, as per: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

If you want to handle the orientation change in the code of your activity, add the following:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="<your-activity>"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    ...
```

In your Activity class, override this method to deal with the orientation change:

```
  @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {}
```

More info:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html
- http://code.hootsuite.com/orientation-changes-on-android/